# Is the ASPX view engine in .NET Core asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core

We have a large .net 4.6 project that is aspx based (not razor).

We need to migrate it to asp.net core.

A year ago or so, it was discussed that the aspx view engine was not yet in core.

Is it now, or will it soon be?

(We need to migrate our app and self host it in kestrel or similar web server)

Comment: no, and most probably never will: https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/1961

Comment: @Alexan ack, that is almost end of the world for me.

Comment: use razor pages, they are more close to webforms.

Comment: but why you need to migrate to .core, just stay in 4.6 or 4.7

Comment: If you really want it, now everything is open sourced, and you can help yourself by creating it.

Comment: @Alexan We need to go to core to self host the app and get out of IIS. (IIS is a deployment chore) But if we go to razor, we can stay on .NET 4.6/4.7, and self host in nancy which is pretty cool.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there are plans for them to bring aspx pages over to core for speed and cross-compatibility reasons.  See Microsoft Documentation here: [Unavailable .NET Core technologies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server#a-need-to-use-net-technologies-not-available-for-net-core)

Comment: Ack. That is really terrible. Our app is too large to port or rewrite.

Comment: @Jonesome Yeah unfortunately we are re-writing an old Web Forms app now.  We used the ASP Net Zero Boilerplate template which was a good base to start and then we created our little own tool to quickly create pages.  It's a ton of up front work but it sets you up for scalability and even gets you ready for mobile. It's the future, going to have to do it eventually.

Answer (score 0):

I was going to suggest using jade, the view engine, since Razor syntax is flexible to accommodate scripts and templates when I discovered that there is an alternate view engine based on jade called pugzor, a pug view engine on Razor

Check it out here - https://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/11/22/creating-a-new-view-engine-in-asp-net-core.aspx

The shorter version of it is, quoted from the same article:

Add a reference to the pugzor.core NuGet package then call .AddPugzor() after .AddMvc() in the Startup.ConfigureServices method